# Order of Bootstrap and CSS files

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me to order the jquery and css references in my asp.net mvc project because some of my files aren't running and aren't being loaded.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> <!-- menu aim -->
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>  <!-- Resource jQuery -->
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
```

Comment: You have several versions of `jQuery`, `modernizr`, `bootstrap` eand `respond`

Comment: You are loading multiple versions of most of the jQuery libraries, such as both the minified and readable versions, which is not necessary. Clean that up first.

Comment: After that, well, include the external libraries on top and then your own scripts and stylesheets.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Still not enough occurences of jQuery. OP also needs [jQuery v3.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js).

Comment: You included all components twice, the minimized version and the normal version. Choose between those please.

Comment: you all have contributed to make me learn more about referencing the javascript and css files. hands-up for all of you :-)

Comment: those who mark negative my question, made me paralyze to do something. make me sad. what if im new here then why you people mark me negative to decrease my points ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to order your files by keeping in mind some points

> **Key point is:**
>  first, put .css files on top like bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css and then jquery.js and jquery.validation.js.

**first: main files comes first**
    i.e.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

**then its predecessor, on which other files are depending.**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't know what really function of some library you initialize but you must remove duplicate same library. you can try like this.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> <!-- menu aim -->
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>  <!-- Resource jQuery -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script> <!-- menu aim -->
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/_references.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>  <!-- Resource jQuery -->
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJavaScript.js"></script>
```

Note : try to sort it from library to customize javascript. For customize javascript, sort it from the highest to the lower priority

It usually works.

Comment: okayy, you're welcome. i think u ought to upvote this if this help u.. :)